# Hash tag based searching on SO

Tags: feature-request

Almost all users search for the required information on Google which present them links for SO and leads them to a particular question.

But, mostly we don't get the answer from the first SO link, we go back to the search results and click on the other results.

Instead can SO index all the relevant questions on that page itself as, "Similar Questions".

It will be similar to making use of hash tags on twitter to faster searching and SO is on a good side because we already have tags.

Comment: You can already search with tags using [Some tag name]

Comment: But my point is different. When I directly open a question from a link or search results, can I get a section of similar questions?

Answer (score 8):

There are two primary utilities for this.

First, tags are *already* a hashtag-style search. Instead of placing the metadata in the post, we're instead separating it from the post. It's literally the exact same metadata, though. See my post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187417/206222). To search for a tag, put it in brackets; e.g. search for `[java]` for questions tagged "java."

Secondly, if you're searching for related questions, there's a related questions list to the right of each question. You can search there, or you can run another search with new keywords.

These utilities already exist in their present form, and this coincides with what you are asking for rather well.

Comment: my bad for not checking these obvious things